# How to fetch locales asynchronously (nuxt.js + i18n + axios)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, nuxt.js

I'd like to get the location asynchronously. Unfortunately my code causes "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error. How can I do it correctly?

So far I've tried to do this by invoking the axios command, inside the messages object.

```
~/plugins/i18n.js

import Vue from "vue";
import VueI18n from "vue-i18n";
import axios from 'axios';

Vue.use(VueI18n);

export default async ({ app, store }) => {
    app.i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale: 'fr',
    fallbackLocale: 'en',
    messages: {
        en: await axios.get('https://some-api/en/locale'),
        fr: await axios.get('https://some-api/fr/locale')
    }
});
```

}

I would like fetch my locales asynchronous, before the page is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in the `beforeCreate` hook  while creating the Vue instance:

```
const i18n = new VueI18n();
new Vue({
  el: rootElement,
  i18n,
  beforeCreate() {
    const vm = this;
    axios.get(url)
      .then((response) => {
        vm.$i18n.setLocaleMessage('en', response.data);
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use middleware:
https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-middleware#the-middleware-property

Or fetch data with axios from module in store and call it in `nuxtServerInit`:

```
export default actions {
async nuxtServerInit({dispatch}){
  await dispatch('apicallmodule/apicallAction')
}
```